# CUDA: Finding Minimum Value in 100x100 Matrix

Tags: c, cuda

i just learned GPU programming and now i have a task to find a minimum value from 100x100 matrix by doing parallel at CUDA. i have try this code, but it's not showing the answer, instead of showing my initiate value `hmin = 9999999`.can anyone give me the right code? oh, the code is in C lang.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size (100*100)

//Kernel Functions & Variable
__global__ void FindMin(int* mat[100][100],int* kmin){
    int b=blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int k=blockIdx.y+threadIdx.y*blockDim.y;

    if(mat[b][k] < kmin){
       kmin = mat[b][k];
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Declare Variabel
    int i,j,hmaks=0,hmin=9999999,hsumin,hsumax; //Host Variable
    int *da[100][100],*dmin,*dmaks,*dsumin,*dsumax; // Device Variable
    FILE *baca; //for opening txt file
    char buf[4]; //used for fscanf
    int ha[100][100],b; //matrix shall be filled by "b"

    //1: Read txt File
    baca=fopen("MatrixTubes1.txt","r");
    if (!baca){
       printf("Hey, it's not even exist"); //Checking File, is it there?
    }

    i=0;j=0; //Matrix index initialization
    if(!feof(baca)){ //if not end of file then do
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
           for(j = 0; j < 100; j++){
              fscanf(baca,"%s",buf); //read max 4 char
              b=atoi(buf); //parsing from string to integer
              ha[i][j]=b; //save it to my matrix
           }
        }
    }
    fclose(baca);
    //all file has been read
    //time to close the file

    //Sesi 2: Allocation data di GPU
    cudaMalloc((void **)&da, size*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dmin, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dmaks, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dsumin, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dsumax, sizeof(int));

    //Sesi 3: Copy data to Device
    cudaMemcpy(da, &ha, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dmin, &hmin, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dmaks, &hmaks, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Sesi 4: Call Kernel

    FindMin<<<100,100,1>>>(da,dmin);

    //5: Copy from Device to Host

    cudaMemcpy(&hmin, dmin, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //6: Print that value
    printf("Minimum Value = %i \n",hmin);

    system("pause"); return 0;
 }
```

this is my result

```
 Minimum Value = 9999999
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be if(*mat[b][k] < *kmin) in FindMin()?

Comment: yes, i think when all variable is int* it's not a problem. but i've tried that before this code posted. it doesn't work

Comment: It is a problem. There might be other issues. Put a print before if(mat[b][k] < kmin). Print both the values. You will find the issue easily.

Comment: One more question. I don't understand how are you calculating indices b and k. Are they varying for all (100, 100)? For me it looks like you are comparing kmin with a single value of the 2D the array.

Comment: oh, that's my problem too. i do not fully understand how to indexing in matrix.

Comment: You need to use two for loops. You have used it once during matrix initialization.  ha[i][j]=b;

Answer (score 1):

I saw a few issues in your code.

- As mentioned in the comments from MayurK, you got the indexing wrong.
- Also as MayurK said, you are comparing two pointers and not the values they point to.
- You kernel invocation code asks for 100 x 100 x 1 grid, with each block containing just 1 thread. This is very bad in terms of efficiency. Also, because of this, your `b` and `k` will only range from 0 to 99, as the `threadIdx.x` will always be zero.
- Finally, all threads will be running in parallel, resulting in a race condition in `kmin = mat[b][k]` (which should be `*kmin` by the way). When you fixed the indexing problem, all threads in the same block will write to the location in global memory at same time. You should use `atomicMin()` or a parallel reduction for finding the minimum value in parallel.